# kivy putting video inside a Canvas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, kivy, kivy-language

i want to put a video inside a canvas.

i'm using images inside them just fine but when i use videos it triggers some errors `Unknown <mp4> type, no loader found.` i do not know where is the probleme.

this is my code for the image :

```html
with self.canvas:
            self.bg = Rectangle(source='mahrez.jpg', pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
```

but instead of the image i want to use a video

Comment: Use a Video widget, or if you want to use a Rectangle look at the Video widget's code to see how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want by using `kivy.core.video` and using that to set the texture of the `Rectangle`:

```
from kivy.core.video import Video as CoreVideo
.
.
.
    with self.canvas:
        self.bg = Rectangle(source='mahrez.jpg', pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
    self.video = CoreVideo()
    self.video.bind(on_frame=self.set_bg_texture)
    self.video.filename = 'BigBuckBunny.mp4'

    # just a delay to show that the original image is shown first
    Clock.schedule_once(self.start_vid, 3)

def start_vid(self, dt):
    self.video.play()

def set_bg_texture(self, *args):
    self.bg.texture = self.video.texture
```